# Why don't I need "\n" to add a line in the file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook and learning to read and write files. Now I created this file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dlzg.png)

To add a line, I used the append mode and since append mode takes the cursor to the end of the txt file, I should use "\n" but I am able to add a new line without it. I don't understand why.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57dBa.png)

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `print()` adds a new line in your console? Try `print("text", end="")`

Comment: Never post code as images, try to post it as it is.

Comment: Have you read about `%%writefile` that how does it function?

Comment: No, I have not read. I am just going through a lecture of Jose Portilla on Udemy and in that lecture, he had to add "\n" in order to go to the next line.